# Restore files from external USB after deleting .git

Tags: filesystems, usb, git, macintosh, restore

I have 20 years of work on my USB. After deleting .git files. I ran this command in the terminal:

sudo find . | grep .git | xargs rm -rf

I lost all folders and files.
When I look in Finder I was shocked: all my projects were gone. Structure under different folders was gone. Everything was deleted.
 How? Why? Is there any solution to restore..? 
The USB is mounted under /*BACKUP*/DATA/

Can anybody help me to recover files under same structure and filenames?

Comment: To clarify, you deleted data from a local disk, but you have a backup on a USB drive, and you are asking how to restore from that backup? Or do you mean that you deleted files from your only copy and ask how to proceed (e.g., make an image of the USB drive and proceed from that)?

Comment: I have only backup on USB. Than I type above command in terminal to delete .git files from all folders on usb. But instead, command delete all of my files in from folder..Why..?

Comment: How I can restore my files from only backup (usb)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain why all your files are deleted you run 
`find .` which just search everything and after that pipe it to `grep .git` which filter all files that have *any char + git* in them that include files as Fugitive.txt Digit.md etc etc and on all of them you run `rm -rf` And if you have misfortune to have directory named e.g `Digitized` it come in the same bucket.

I do not know how to restore your files but my best advice it to stop using it as any more IO operation on it will make restoration impossible.

You could try also some of the software in this [list](http://www.toptenreviews.com/software/backup-recovery/best-mac-data-recovery-software/)